# How to wait for SerialPort DataReceived event handler while in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, backgroundworker

I am working on a C# Windows Forms application that interfaces with a digital multimeter via a serial port. In my BackgroundWorker's `DoWork` event handler I send several commands to the multimeter, such as to take voltage/resistance measurements, and then request the data back. Then the serial port's `DataReceived` event is raised, and I do some brief processing in that method; I use `ReadLine()` and store the data in a string. But I think because `DoWork` and `DataReceived` are asynchronous, I will not be getting the correct values if I try to use that string in `DoWork` immediately after the statement that requests the data; I have to wait for `DataReceived` to finish. Currently I just have a `Thread.Sleep(100)` after every such statement. I'm sure this isn't the best solution, is there a more efficient way to somehow wait for `DataReceived` to finish, or otherwise deal with this threading issues?

Comment: There's no point in using DataReceived if you need the data in a worker thread.  Just call one of the Read methods directly.  It will block until data is available.  You don't care that it blocks, it is not the UI thread and won't freeze your user interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a background worker at all, since you have asynchronous rather than synchronous work to do.  Instead just send the request and do whatever needs to be done with the response entirely in the event handler.

Comment: I don't understand. The data request itself is what raises DataReceived. I can't put it in that event's handler. Also isn't a background worker intended to be used for asynchronous operations? I'm doing a lot of multimeter work in the background.

Comment: @user2498300 When you send the request the `DataReceived` event won't be fired immediately.  If you got your result immediately it would just be the return value of the method you call.  The entire reason for having an event is because some time takes place between when you send the request and when you get the response.  You'll need to do your work in the `DataRecieved` event handler.  That's the appropriate way to solve this problem.  No, BGW isn't designed to fire off asynchronous work.  It's designed to take synchronous work and perform it outside of the UI thread, making it asynchronous.

Comment: I see what you are saying now, I misread your initial response. Now my problem is that I need to perform different operations on the requested data at different points in time, and I don't see how I can deal with it all in the DataReceived event handler alone. Sometimes I'm storing the data in various arrays, at other times I'm adding and subtracting to adjust inputs to the multimeter, etc.

Comment: @user2498300 Without knowing more specifics that's hard to say.  Perhaps you need to, at certain points in time, remove the previous event handler and add a new one, or perhaps the class that your event handler is in needs to have some state that is changed that affects what it does.

Comment: Is it possible to add and remove event handlers while the code is running?

Comment: I may look into it then. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: @user2498300 I would never put a blocking call in the DataReceived event handler.  Since you have the BGW, send the commands, and issue the blocking read(s) in it as Hans suggested.  If you are going to use the DataReceived event handler then use non-blocking calls until you have enough data, then process it.  Add / Removing event handlers is kludgy, at best.

Comment: @Servy - Only one SerialPort event can be active at any one time, so if you have blocking calls in the event handler, that are creating new SerialPort events, then you can have issues.

Comment: @dbasnett I haven't seen anything to indicate that the OP would need a second event to fire while the first event handler is still running, merely that the first event handler is performing some action that will result in there being a second event handler at some point after it has finished.  If my interpretation was incorrect, by all means propose an alternative solution.

Comment: @Servy - I did.  Do what Hans suggested in his comment to the original question.